# inserting null date in postgres

Tags: postgresql, null, sql-insert

I am inserting a null date with a `INSERT ... SELECT FROM` statement in sql

```sql
CREATE TABLE null_date (
  id         bigserial PRIMARY KEY
, some_date  date
);

WITH date_data (some_date) AS (
  VALUES (null)
)
INSERT INTO null_date (some_date)
SELECT some_date
FROM date_data;
```

and it fails with

```
ERROR:  column "some_date" is of type date but expression is of type text
LINE 5: SELECT some_date
               ^
HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
```

However, if I try to insert it directly, it works

```
INSERT INTO null_date (some_date)
VALUES (null)
```

can somebody please help me understand what's happening here? Here is the link to [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/sk4jWaS7). Thanks

Comment: Maybe casting it explicitly into type date with `::date`? https://dbfiddle.uk/PDzMtTmg

Comment: Or use the standard CAST() to cast the content

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that the `VALUES` statement and consequently the `WITH` clause will treat the NULL value as type `text`, because PostgreSQL doesn't know which data type the NULL should be. You don't have that problem with `INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...)`, because here PostgreSQL knows right away that the NULL value with `unknown` type will be inserted into a certain column, so it will resolve it to the target data type.

In cases where PostgreSQL cannot guess the data type from context, you had better use an explicit type cast:

```
WITH date_data (some_date) AS (
  VALUES (CAST(null AS date))
)
INSERT INTO null_date (some_date)
SELECT some_date
FROM date_data;
```

PostgreSQL used to behave differently in cases like this, but [commit 1e7c4bb0049](https://git.postgresql.org/gitweb/?p=postgresql.git;a=commit;h=1e7c4bb0049732ece651d993d03bb6772e5d281a) changed that in 2017. Read the commit message for an explanation.

Comment: This shows that PostGreSQL does not respects Codd's rule 3 about NULLs... " _Null values (distinct from the empty character string or a string of blank characters and distinct from zero or any other number) are supported in fully relational DBMS for representing missing information and inapplicable information in a systematic way, **independent of data type**_ ."

Comment: @SQLpro I know that this is pure polemic, so I won't repeat my mistake of attempting a fact-centered discussion with you. I'll leave it to the reader to form their opinion.

Comment: It is not polemic. It is fact. The fact that PostGreSQL does not respects many Codd's rules [link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codd%27s_12_rules)...